# Password getting autofiiled in react-redux-firebase application in every inpu box with type="password", when it is saved in browser

Tags: html, passwords

I created a react-redux-firebase application. On login , I saved user's email and password to browser, so that It will get auto filled in input boxes. It works fine.

But in another components "Profile" ,where I want to delete a user re-authenticates with current password but this input box is also filled , how can I prevent this? I mean using setting "autoFill" as false as a option but I don't want browser to recognize the input in profile as input boxes in login. For security concern as anyone can set "autoFill" to "true" by inspecting.

```
<input type="password" />
```

I just wrote this and it got auto filled, atleast browser should match name property. How to prevent this?

```
<InputBase
          placeholder="Search…"
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
          onKeyDown={(event)=>{if(event.key=="Enter"){history.push('/products')} }}
          classes={{
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            input: classes.inputInput,
          }}
          value={searchValue}
          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
        />
```

Even when I click on profile page "search" box gets fiiled with my email address saved in browser.

how to prevent this?

Comment: Do you have an issue with a password type field, or a username/email type field? You question/issue is a bit unclear.

Comment: yes, issue with pasword type field. Any input with type "password" gets autofilled with password present in browser. Even in the signup component, if a user has already saved his password in browser during login and then logouts and another user try to signup on same computer (same browser ,it might happen in family or friends), signup field also contains password and email field having autofilled  with previously saved data of other user. other family members can inspect the password.

Comment: Try `autocomplete="new-password"` for inputs that aren't actually password fields, this still allows for masked input but won't necessarily be honored by browser as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password.

Answer (score 0):

> For security concern as anyone can set "autoFill" to "true" by inspecting.

Anyone who could set `autoFill` to `true` when inspecting could also create a complete `<input>` by inspecting or simply go into the browser settings and look at the password as they seem to have physical control over the machine.

At that point it is not for you to care about and everything you do might impact accessibility or actually reduce the quality of passwords used because people start re-using passwords instead of using a password manager.

Setting autofill to false is okay, but every further step you take (e.g. preventing copy & paste or preventing password managers to detect password fields that could be filled up after user interaction) is detrimental to the user's security and goes against the [NIST guidelines](https://auth0.com/blog/dont-pass-on-the-new-nist-password-guidelines/).

Comment: I think I can add initial values just like formik has to prevent autofill.

Comment: You can also use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password , too.   
But generally, please don't interfere with that stuff too much though. When a user chooses to use a password manager, that's their choice and it might have all kinds of reasons up to them just not being able to type because of a disability and relying on that autofill.

It's not up to you to question the user's security model.